# Initializing class constants in Swift

Tags: swift

I was trying to do something like this (it is a contrived example for demonstration purposes only):

```
class Test {
  let hello = "hello"
  let world = "world"
  let phrase: String {
    return self.hello + self.world
  }
}
```

but you can't use `let` for computed properties in Swift. Is there a way to do this without having to write an `init()` method? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason `let` doesn't work on a read-only calculated property is because it's used to state that the property's actual *value* will never change after being set – not that the property is read-only. As the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259) say (emphasis mine):

> You must declare computed properties — including read-only computed
>   properties — **as variable properties with the var keyword, because their
>   value is not fixed.** The let keyword is only used for constant
>   properties, to indicate that their values cannot be changed once they
>   are set as part of instance initialization.

You therefore need to use `var` in order to reflect the fact that a calculated property's value could change at any time, as you're creating it on the fly when accessing it. Although in your code, this can't happen – as your `hello` and `world` properties are `let` constants themselves. However, Swift is unable to infer this, so you still have to use `var`.

For example:

```
class Test {
    let hello = "hello"
    let world = "world"
    var phrase: String {
        return self.hello + self.world
    }
}
```

<sup>(This doesn't change the readability of the property – as because you haven't provided it with a setter, it's still read-only)</sup>

However in your case, you might want to consider using a [lazy property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID255) instead, as your `hello` and `world` properties are constants. A lazy property is created when it's first accessed, and keeps its value for the rest of its lifetime – meaning you won't have to keep on concatenating two constants together every time you access it.

For example:

```
class Test {
    let hello = "hello"
    let world = "world"
    lazy var phrase: String = {
        return self.hello + self.world
    }()
}
```

Another characteristic of `let` properties is that their value should always be known before initialisation. Because the value of a lazy property might not be known before then, you also need to define it as a `var`.

---

If you're still adamant on wanting a `let` property for this, then as far as I can see, you have two options.

The first is the neatest (although you've said you don't want to do it) – you can assign your `phrase` property in the initialiser. As long as you do this before the `super.init` call, you don't have to deal with optionals. For example:

```
class Test {
    let hello = "hello"
    let world = "world"
    let phrase: String

    init() {
        phrase = hello+world
    }
}
```

You simply cannot do it inline, as `self` at that scope refers to the static class, not an instance of the class. Therefore you cannot access the instance members, and have to use `init()` or a lazy/calculated property.

The second option is pretty hacky – you can mirror your `hello` and `world` properties at class level, so you can therefore access them inline in your `phrase` declaration. For example:

```
class Test {
    static let hello = "hello"
    static let world = "world"

    // for some reason, Swift has trouble inferring the type
    // of the static mirrored versions of these properties
    let hello:String = Test.hello
    let world:String = Test.world

    let phrase = hello+world
}
```

If you don't actually need your `hello` or `world` properties as instance properties, then you can just make them `static` – which will solve your problem.

Comment: It's a shame that the immutability of `hello` and `world` (both using `let`) doesn't transitively apply to `phrase`. Conceptually, a derivation from immutable properties should itself also be immutable.

Comment: @AMomchilov True, it certainly would be neat for the compiler to be able to infer whether a calculated property could be considered immutable or not – however you should consider the impact on the compiler design. You'd have to search through the entire body of the calculated property, including any method calls, any other calculated properties, in order to work out if the result is immutable. The end result could be quite messy and unintuitive – and potentially have more edge cases than the current syntax.

Comment: I'm sure the compiler would be doing that for 100 other very niche optimization reasons, anyway. I'll bring this up in the swift-evolution mailing list.

Comment: @AMomchilov Good idea, I'd certainly be interested in what they have to say about it – although I maintain my initial scepticism. I have no doubt that the compiler is able to such things already for optimisation reasons, I'm just concerned that the results may not be immediately intuitive to the user (given that Swift is designed to be pretty intuitive).

Comment: Why not? As far as interface is concerned, there shouldn't be anything special distinguishing `phrase` from `hello` and `world`. The fact that `phrase` happens to be a `String` returned from a computed property and not a `String` literal is just an implementation detail, which isn't relevant to the interface.

Comment: @AMomchilov True, but bear in mind here that the `+` operator is a function  – meaning that the immutability of the property is now tied to the internal implementation of what `+` returns. Sure, in this case it could never return anything other than `"helloworld"` – but consider other functions. Your property could be happy being a `let` one moment, and then not happy the next moment if you change the internal implementation of a given function it depends on – which could get messy.

Comment: Yeah, there would need to be a mechanism to determine/annotate function purity. Although in simple cases, like this would, iit could be easy, as the `+` operation would be precomputed at compile time to a string constant, anyway

Answer (score 2):

Yes to make it work as computed properties, replace let to var. 
Like,

```
class Test {
  let hello = "hello"
  let world = "world"
  var phrase: String {
     return self.hello + self.world
  }
}
```

This way you can use it without init()